# featured image inside post

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want the featured image of a post to display not only in the blog list view, but also inside the post (when i press "Read More..."). How do i do that?

I pasted this

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
 the_post_thumbnail('full');
}
```

in single.php just before the_post();. It looks like this:

```
while (have_posts()) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
      the_post_thumbnail('full');
    } 
    the_post();
    get_template_part('content', 'single');
}
```

But the image shows up, above the title. How do i make it show after the title, just like in the blog list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PatJ's answer affords the most control over the placement of the image but involves editing the theme, which may or may not be wise, or possible, depending on the circumstance, so an alternative is to add a filter to `the_content`.

```
function add_thumb_wpse_100914($content) {
    // check that we are on a 'single' post display and...
    // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    if ( is_single() && has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
      $content = get_the_post_thumbnail(null,'full').$content;
    } 
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','add_thumb_wpse_100914');
```

Comment: Where exactly do i paste this code?

Comment: @user33351 in functions.php of your current theme

Comment: Well, now the image does show up inside the post, but it has a side effect. The image shows twice in the blog list view. How can i fix that?

Comment: You can put that in `functions.php`, in a plugin file, or in a must-use plugin. To fix the double image in the blog list, add an `is_single` condition. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks man. That is exactly what i wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file in your theme called `content-single.php` (if it's not there, look instead for `content.php`).  Inside that file there will be a line like `the_title()`.  If you put your `the_post_thumbnail( 'full' );` after that line, it should appear after the title in the single page view.

#### Rationale

`the_post()` sets up the data for the next post in The Loop (in the case of a single page, it sets up *the* post/page).  The next line in your `single.php` -- `get_template_part()` -- is where the post/page view is actually assembled; it should contain `the_title()`, `the_content()`, etc.

#### References

Codex:
[`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)
[`get_template_part()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)
[`the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)